# Vim goes to background when rearranging window layout

Tags: shell, arch-linux, vim, background-process, i3

The GIF below shows what I'm observing. If I do the following

1. I send Vim to background with <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> only once,
2. come back to it via <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>,
3. then open another terminal, causing the original one to resize

upon performing step 3, Vim is sent to background automatically.

This seems to happen irrespective of the shell. In the GIF below you'll see that happening with both `bash` and `sh`, but I can also reproduce it in `fish`.

This is clearly being a fairly annoying problem, which I started experiencing yesterday. Initially (when I asked [this question on vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/help-in-troubleshooting-strange-behavior-when-resuming-vim-from-background)), I thought it was related to two specific plugins, but as you can see from the GIF below, I can reproduce it without using any Vim settings (launching it with the `-u NONE` option). However, I've not been playing around with config files, recently, so I don't understand why this problem suddenly popped up yesterday. Maybe some system update?

[image]

Comment: This is a bug. See vim's issue tracker for the bug report: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/9586 (seems like the fix is going to be included in one of the next releases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment this was precisely [issue #9586](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/9586) that was indeed fixed.